# Generate separate plots for each group of records in dataset

Tags: data-visualization, excel

I have a large csv file with around 45,000 rows and about 6 columns.

The columns are set-up like:

```
Module, File-path, Status, Version-Old, Version-New, Change-diff
```

*Change-diff* is simply the result of doing: *New - Old*.

There are around 30 different modules and I want to perform analysis and create different graphs for each module based on the change-diff.

I want to know the number of "rows" for each 'module' - I guess I can just count the number of each module name for the Module column to work that out.

I'm wondering if there is any program that I can use to make my job easier, I'm currently trying to plug it all into Excel but I'm not sure how I can create graphs for each module instead of one big graph for all modules.

Would R, SPSS or Matlab be a better option? Or anything else?

EDIT:
Just expanding on what the data looks like.

```
Module,  Path,      Status,  Old,  New,  Change
modA,    modA/a/a,  1,       11,   19,   8
modA,    modA/a/b,  1,       2,    4,    2
modA,    modA/a/c,  1,       0,    1,    1
modA,    modA/b/c,  0,       0,    1,    1
modA,    modA/b/a,  1,       7,    12,   5
modB,    modB/a/a,  1,       8,    9,    1
modB,    modB/a/b,  0,       0,    1,    1
modB,    modB/a/c,  1,       4,    10,   6
modC,    modC/a/a,  0,       0,    4,    4
modC,    modC/a/b,  1,       0,    3,    3
```

So I want to analyse all of modA based on Change (and possibly based on Old vs New etc.)
Then analyse all of modB, modC etc. all in the same way but in separate graphs, automatically because of the amount of data I'm dealing with.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little ambiguous ("different graphs for each module" doesn't mean quite the same thing as "separate graphs for each module"), but my impression is that you're trying to create the same plot or set of plots using only the data from each module, for all of your modules.  This is how I'd do that in R:

```
# Strings ain't factors
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


# Set up a folder for plot output
plotdir <- file.path(getwd(), "plots")
dir.create(plotdir)

# Load the data
# You'll use a read.csv() statement
modrows <- read.csv("blah.csv")

# This is the structure of your data as output by `dput()` - this is nice
# to include with a question because it can easily be pasted into the console
# to recreate any object
modrows <- structure(list(Module = c("modA", "modA", "modA", "modA", "modA",
                                     "modB", "modB", "modB", "modC", "modC"), 
                          Path = c("modA/a/a", "modA/a/b", "modA/a/c", 
                                   "modA/b/c", "modA/b/a", "modB/a/a", 
                                   "modB/a/b", "modB/a/c", "modC/a/a", 
                                   "modC/a/b"), 
                          Status = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), 
                          Old = c(11L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 8L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L), 
                          New = c(19L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 9L, 1L, 10L, 4L, 3L), 
                          Change = c(8L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 3L)), 
                     .Names = c("Module", "Path", "Status", 
                                "Old", "New", "Change"), 
                     class = "data.frame", 
                     row.names = c(NA, -10L))



# There's nothing below that can't be done in base R, but I'm partial to plyr
# and ggplot2 for this kind of work.  In plyr, the first two letters of most
# functions indicate the input and output data structures - ddply takes and
# outputs a data.frame, dlplyr takes a DF and puts out a list, etc.
# d_ply splits up a data.frame but produces nothing.  That's fine because
# I'm just using it as a glorified for loop here.
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Get the extreme values of each variable so that you can set reasonable
# axis limits to keep your plots comparable
minvals <- apply(modrows[ , -(1:3)], 2, min)
maxvals <- apply(modrows[ , -(1:3)], 2, max)

# Take modrows, split it up by Module, and perform a function on each chunk
# (which is aliased as "x" for the function)
d_ply(modrows, .var = "Module", .progress = "text", .fun = function(x){

    # A really simple histogram of Change for each module
    ggplot(x, aes(x = Change)) +
        geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) +
        xlim(minvals["Change"], maxvals["Change"]) +
        opts(title = paste("Change in ", x$Module[1], sep = ""))

    # Save to the plot directory
    ggsave(file = file.path(plotdir, 
                            paste("Change in ", x$Module[1], ".png", sep = ""))
    )

    # A slightly more complicated plot - subhistograms of Change by Status
    ggplot(x, aes(x = Change)) +
        geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) +
        facet_wrap( ~ Status) +
        xlim(minvals["Change"], maxvals["Change"]) +
        opts(title = paste("Change by status in ", x$Module[1], sep = ""))
    ggsave(file = file.path(plotdir, paste("Change by status in ", 
                                           x$Module[1], ".png", sep = ""))
    )

    # Comparing Old and New
    ggplot(x, aes(x = Old, y = New)) +
        geom_point() +
        xlim(minvals["Old"], maxvals["Old"]) +
        ylim(minvals["New"], maxvals["New"]) +
        opts(title = paste("Old vs. new in ", x$Module[1], sep = ""))

    ggsave(file = file.path(plotdir, paste("Old vs. new in", 
                                           x$Module[1], ".png", sep = ""))
    )

    }
)
```

Comment: Ah, oops, my bad - I put the title in after I wrote up everything and didn't really think that "different" and "separate" would be interrelated differently.

Your script works perfectly and is very informative, now I'll just tweak the way I do the graphs and what I have to analyse. Seems I have quite a few outliers so I'll want to remove those but I'm sure I'll find the answer to that easily.
Many thanks!

Comment: No worries - I'm glad this helps.  Don't be too hasty to remove outliers!  I can imagine it's problematic if it's causing your axis scales to change dramatically, but it's probably better to set the axes to accomodate the full range of values first, and then decide to remove outliers later.  I'll tweak my code a bit to give you an example.

Comment: I tested your code to remove outliers but it didn't quite come out right. I have a lot of data that range between 1-10 in the 'change' column but then once or twice per module there is something much higher at 50 or even 200. I'm not sure if your outlier code is based on 'each module' or the 'whole column'?

Comment: Nope - it's not code to remove outliers, it's code to ensure that all the plots are on the same scale, even in the presence of outliers, so that plots from different modules can still be easily compared to each other.  I'd argue that you should leave your outliers in unless you have a really good reason to take them out - kinda depends on your purpose.  At any rate, handling outliers is a sufficiently large problem that you should probably start a new question for it if you can't find an existing answer on the site.

Comment: Ah yes, re-reading it now makes sense, especially when I check the comment to explain it above... clearly wasn't thinking last night :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use R, as it has strong general-purpose programming capabilities.  You can define a plot for each module, and then apply that plot to the subset of your data represented by that module.

Something like this would work, although your actual plots will probably be much more complicated:

```
Module <- sample(1:3,100,replace=TRUE)
Changediff <- rnorm(100)
Data <- data.frame(Module,Changediff)

graph1 <- function(x) {
    hist(x)
}

graph2 <- function(x) {
    plot(density(x))
}

graph3 <- function(x) {
    boxplot(x)
}

graph1(Data[Data$Module==1,'Changediff'])
graph2(Data[Data$Module==2,'Changediff'])
graph3(Data[Data$Module==3,'Changediff'])
```

Furthermore, you can use the `pdf()` function in R to collect your graphs into a single pdf, which you can then share with colleagues.

Comment: I've never really used R before, but reading through it and trying to understand your script.

The first two lines you are just generating the data and setting it to a variable? Then the 3rd line is used for adding it all into a 'frame' (like a table with 2 columns)?

So, I think I can use this instead:
Data <- read.csv("myFile.csv",header=T)
Module <- Data$Module
Change <- Data$Change

I'm unsure about the graph lines at the bottom:
graph1(Data[Data$Module==1,'Change'])

Would that select just each 'row' where Module == 1?
How would I select for-each module, not knowing the value at each row?

Comment: @Dan2k3k4: Yes.  The `Data[Data$Module==1,]` command selects every row where Module equals 1.  `Data[Data$Module==1,'Changediff']` does the same, but selects the `Changediff` column.  If you don't know the unique values of `Module`, you can use `unique(Module)` to find them.

Comment: The `by()` function is good for looping over subsets of the data. The code here would look something like `by(Data, factor(Data$Module), do.one.plot())`, where `do.one.plot()` does all the plotting commands you want, for a given data frame.